# Python - How to do a Logical calculation from Text column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to transform texts into number with calculations.

I could not find a way to come out with the result. At this moment, I am using powerquery to split them by "," then mapping all columns with number, which consumes too long to do this action.
May I know is there any way to do this in Python? Preferred to be in Pandas, will be okay if other methods though. Appreciated with it.

It is hoping I could translate "Text Column" to "Result"
For example: from "Back A, Back C" --> "0/5" and result in dataframe format.

Assuming

A=4

B=1

C=1

(Front/Back)

Please see the code as below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['Front A', '4/0'], ['Back A, Back C', '0/5'], ['Front B, Back C', '1/1'],['Front A, Back A', '4/4'],['Front A, Front B, Front C, Back B', '6/1'],['Front A, Front A, Front B, Back B, Back C', '9/2']], columns=['Text column', 'Result'])
df
                                 Text column Result
0                                    Front A    4/0
1                             Back A, Back C    0/5
2                            Front B, Back C    1/1
3                            Front A, Back A    4/4
4          Front A, Front B, Front C, Back B    6/1
5  Front A, Front A, Front B, Back B, Back C    9/2
```

Comment: Thanks for providing input data. Two more things: 1) What have you tried and 2) What is your expected output (in dataframe format)?

Comment: Thanks @DavidErickson, I have updated the question.

Comment: thank you for sharing what you have tried with PowerQuery, what is the expected output? from the above input data?

Comment: @DavidErickson, the result column is the expected output that I hope could be extracted from the "text column". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try with `pd.Series.str.findall`:

```
maps = {"A":4,"B":1,"C":1}

Front=df['Text column'].str.findall('Front ([ABC])')
Front=pd.Series([sum([*filter(None, map(maps.get, x))]) for x in Front]).astype(str)

Back=df['Text column'].str.findall('Back ([ABC])')
Back=pd.Series([sum([*filter(None, map(maps.get, x))]) for x in Back]).astype(str)

df['result']=Front+'/'+Back
```

---

An approach using `pd.Series.str.extractall`:

```
maps = {"A":4,"B":1,"C":1,'xyz':0}
msk=df['Text column'].str.contains('Front') &df['Text column'].str.contains('Back')
df.loc[~msk, 'Text column']=df.loc[~msk, 'Text column']+' xyz'

Front=df['Text column'].str.extractall('Front ([ABC])|(xyz)').droplevel(1)
Front=Front[0].map(maps).groupby(Front.index).sum().astype(int).astype(str)

Back=df['Text column'].str.extractall('Back ([ABC])|(xyz)').droplevel(1)
Back=Back[0].map(maps).groupby(Back.index).sum().astype(int).astype(str)

df=df.assign(**{'Text column': df['Text column'].str.replace(' xyz','')}).assign(result=Front+'/'+Back)
```

---

Another approach using `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Front A'], ['Back A, Back C'], ['Front B, Back C'],['Front A, Back A'],['Front A, Front B, Front C, Back B'],['Front A, Front A, Front B, Back B, Back C']], columns=['Text column'])
temp=df['Text column'].str.replace(' ','')

maps = {"A":4,"B":1,"C":1}

df['Front']=temp.replace('Front', '',regex=True).apply(lambda x: sum(maps[i]  for i in x.split(',') if 'Back' not in i)).astype(str)+'\\'
df['Back']=temp.replace('Back', '',regex=True).apply(lambda x: sum(maps[i]  for i in x.split(',') if 'Front' not in i)).astype(str)

df=df.assign(result=df['Front']+df['Back']).drop(columns =['Front', 'Back'])
```

---

All outputs:

```
df
                                 Text column result
0                                    Front A    4\0
1                             Back A, Back C    0\5
2                            Front B, Back C    1\1
3                            Front A, Back A    4\4
4          Front A, Front B, Front C, Back B    6\1
5  Front A, Front A, Front B, Back B, Back C    9\2
```

Comment: I have tested the script you provided and find them workable with simplification. Really brilliant!
Thanks a lot with your help

Comment: You're welcome! As a suggestion, add what have you tried so far in future questions, including this, please! :)

Answer (score 1):

The expected output is vague, but if you want to substitute and sum the strings, here's how

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, df['Text column'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1).drop('Text column', axis=1).fillna(0)
df1 = df1.replace('A$', 4, regex=True).replace('B$',1, regex=True).replace('C$',1, regex=True)
df1['total'] = df1.sum(axis=1)

df1
Result  0   1   2   3   4   total
0   4/0 4   0   0   0   0   4
1   0/5 4   1   0   0   0   5
2   1/1 1   1   0   0   0   2
3   4/4 4   4   0   0   0   8
4   6/1 4   1   1   1   0   7
5   9/2 4   4   1   1   1   11
```

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners, this is the current way I am handling this conversion.
And I am trying to find out is there any ways which could achieve the same output with less complexity

Comment: So, can't you demonstrate your approach ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

simple way: using `lambda`

```
In [59]: maps = {"A":4,"B":1,"C":1}

In [60]: df['Front_sum'] = df['Text column'].apply(lambda x: sum([maps[y.strip().split(" ")[1]] for y in x.split(",") if y.strip().split(" ")[0]=="Front"]))

In [61]: df['Back_sum'] = df['Text column'].apply(lambda x: sum([maps[y.strip().split(" ")[1]] for y in x.split(",") if y.strip().split(" ")[0]=="Back"]))

In [62]: df['result2'] = df['Front_sum'].astype(str) + "/" + df['Back_sum'].astype(str)

In [63]: df
Out[63]:
                                 Text column Result  Front_sum  Back_sum result2
0                                    Front A    4/0          4         0     4/0
1                             Back A, Back C    0/5          0         5     0/5
2                            Front B, Back C    1/1          1         1     1/1
3                            Front A, Back A    4/4          4         4     4/4
4          Front A, Front B, Front C, Back B    6/1          6         1     6/1
5  Front A, Front A, Front B, Back B, Back C    9/2          9         2     9/2
```

Comment: Thanks @Akhilesh_IN, the solution you provided solve the problem and this is a great help to me